# Creating a grid with square divs that stack on mobile

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a grid of 4 square divs that stack on top of each other when the browser is resized to mobile size. I also need to put vertically and horizontally centered text in each div. To make things even more complicated for me, each div's width is defined as a percentage, not as an absolute value.

Is this even possible to achieve?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Have you tried anything so far? StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service and expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showcasing the specific problem you are facing in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the site :)

Comment: Yes, this is possible. It is done every day.

Comment: Thanks that was really helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible. I prefer Flexbox for this. Read up on it e.g. [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)